# Pushing an embedded div beneath its grandparent using Bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

We have a Bootstrap page where we have a grandparent div, that contains a left and right div. Inside the right div is another 'pair' of left and right divs. We need the last div mentioned to push underneath its grandparent when viewed on mobile devices. Here's some code of what's been started:

https://codepen.io/Codewalker/pen/aaPRrz

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container" style="background:#ddd">
<div class="num-container">
    <div class="num-thumb">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/71x389/000000/fff&text=Side" class="img-responsive imgNum">
    </div>
    <div class="num-content" style="background:#ddd">
        <h2 class="num-title">Grandparent goes right here</h2>
        <p>This along with that image off to the left is the grandparent div. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. </p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <h5>Content col-sm-5</h5>
                <p>Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7" style="background:orange">
                <div class="vid-container">
                    <div class="vid-thumb">
                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/17x158/000000/fff" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="vid-content">
                      <h5>Content col-sm-7</h5>
                      <p>For mobile devices, this needs to wrap underneath the entire gray div. For mobile devices, this needs to wrap underneath the entire gray div.For mobile devices, this needs to wrap underneath the entire gray div.For mobile devices, this needs to wrap underneath the entire gray div.For mobile devices, this needs to wrap underneath the entire gray div. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try putting copies of the div in both places, and have `.hidden-xs-down` on the inside div, and `.hidden-sm-up` on the popped-out div.

Comment: @Ruzihm - Are you referring to duplicating the content and showing one while hiding the other? If so, that was something I thought about, but didn't know if it was a huge no-no.

Comment: Yes, it's not ideal, but was wondering if it was something in particular. Anyway,  something that could work for you: on page load and on viewport resize, check what viewport breakpoint you're at, and to use jQuery to put the div into the appropriate place.  This might be a helpful example to follow for that: https://codepen.io/silverbackdan/pen/YNRBqV